# How to implement data-frame below functionality

Tags: python-3.x

I have data-frame and I am trying to find the max of column and index name.
But I want max should be based of previous occurred max data not the max from starting of column entry for multiple same values.

```
index   a   b   c   d   max   col_name expected_col
0   0   0   0   0   0   a        a
1   0   0   0   0   0   a        a
2   0   3   0   0   3   b        b
3   0   3   0   0   3   b        b
4   0   3   0   0   3   b        b
5   3   3   0   0   3   a        b
6   3   3   0   0   3   a        b
7   3   3   0   3   3   a        b
8   0   3   0   0   3   b        b
9   0   3   0   0   3   b        b
10  0   3   0   0   3   b        b
11  0   0   0   0   0   a        a
12  0   0   0   0   0   a        c
```

I used  `df["max"] = df.max(axis=1)`
        `df["col_name"] = df.idxmax(axis=1)`
But I am not getting how to make it work to get `expected_col`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You added C language tag but I cannot see any C code in your question. Also I cannot see where your question is related to Linux kernel. Please take a few seconds to select only tags related to your problem.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time to post query. Its related to python dataframe